# 60-latin.conf not a directory error in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, kernel, fonts, recovery-mode, cp

I'm not able to login to system. When I tried to reinstall Ubuntu-desktop I'm getting error like

```
Cp: cannot stat: /etc/fonts/conf.d/60-latin.conf not a directory and Plymouth failed with return 1
```

Not able to do anything now. Any solution?

I'm trying this using root menu in Recovery mode

Comment: That's an odd error message. `/etc/fonts/conf.d/60-latin.conf` is not supposed to be a directory. It's a symlink which points to a file.

Comment: Might be permission related issue?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question but I just stumbled on the same issue on my Debian Buster Rasperry pi OS (`Linux raspberrypi 4.19.118-v7+`) and the solution might be helpful for others:

For some reason, the symlinks in `/etc/fonts/conf.d` were not properly configured on my system despite being available. I created the following symlink to fix it:

```
cd /etc/fonts/conf.d
sudo ln -s /usr/share/fontconfig/conf.avail/60-latin.conf
```